# Weighting data sources in a bayesian model (BUGS)

Tags: bayesian, bugs, state-space-models

I use a state space model to fit observations to a population dynamic model (using the BUGS language).

In the "state" part, the dynamic model create a new "state" of the population (i.e. size and structure) for each year modeled.

In the "observation" part, several outputs of the "state" part are fitted to observations given by two different sources.

The size of the population, each year there was observation, is fitted using a lognormal.

```
for (i in 1:N) {
   obsPop[i] ~ dlnorm(log(predictPop[yearObsPop[i]]),prec.obsPop[i])
}
```

The number of individual observed dead, each year there was observation, is fitted using a binomial

```
for (i in 1:N2){
   obsDead[i] ~ dbin(pObsDead, deadPredict[yearObsDead[i]])
}
```

However, N (i.e. the number of year of observation of the population size) is smaller than N2 (i.e. the number of year of observation for mortalities) and the second source of data seems to have an excessive weight in the result.

- How can I do to weight differently each source of data in the global fitting of the model ?

Thanks by advance !

Comment: note to your terminology: *"bayesian model"* is nonsense. No model is bayesian or frequentist; model is an equation, definition, a *thought*. The way how you solve model - the inference - can be bayesian or frequentist, but not the model itself.

Comment: @Tomas Ok, it is noted. However, I would have appreciated a comment directly related to my question and not to the semantic.